# Get version when deserializing binary object

Tags: c#, serialization, version, deserialization

I'm serializing a class using a BinaryFormatter. When I open the created file in a texteditor, I can see that at the beginning, some attributes like namespace, version, cultureInfo, ... are written there. How can I read this version string out when deserializing this file again?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this articles at MSDN:

- [Run-time Serialization, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/02/04/net/default.aspx)
- [Run-time Serialization, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/02/07/net/default.aspx)
- [Run-time Serialization, Part 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx)

The BinaryFormatter has two properties: [`Binder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder.aspx) and [`SurrogateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.surrogateselector.aspx).

With these you are able to interfere the serialization / deserialization process and access these informations. More informations about it can be found in the articles above.

Comment: Perfect, with the Binder and the BindToType function I am able to figure out the prefix string commited as a parameter. There I can parse out the Version. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You probably should read that part like a normal file (read and check bytes).

However, why would you be interested in that part? If you are, than it's best to add your own version attributes in the normal way as other data to be serialized and retrieve it the normal way (by deserialization like all other data).

Remark to your comment:

- If this is the first time, you could write an 'updater', which reads the old file and transforms it with a new (so change the enum values). For the new serialization object, add a version (always, and update it for each version your publish). This case, you can always differ on changes.  By making such an update function, you always can change older versions of data to newer versions. In this case (since you don't have a version), you can assume it is the old version.

Comment: I made something very stupid: There is an enum in the serialized class. And I changed the enum adding some entries in the middle. And now, when I load an older file the old enum int values are not compatible with the current ones. And with reading out the version, my hope was to work version dependend with the "old" enum or the "new" one. But maybe you have a better idea?

Comment: Ok, but how can I detect if it is an old or a new file?

Comment: In the new file there will be a version object, in the old file not. I think if you initialize it with null or an empty string it can be easily detected.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the first time, I have three enum versions. That's why I thought to read out the version...

Comment: Ok, I'm able to figure out the version with the Binder mentioned in the comment below. Now I can use the updater to transform every old file to the current one. Thank you for your help!